# next.js 13 useSession() doesn't retrieve session info when i refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I am making ecommerce site clone using nextjs 13 and in its order page i call useSession(from next-auth/react) to see whether user signed in or not. At first time i visit the page through link navigation there is no problem but when i refresh or i directly visit the page, its stucking in loading state.

order page:

```
"use client";
  ...
const Orders = async () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  
    ...
```

root layout page:

```
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <AuthProvider>
          <BasketProvider>{children}</BasketProvider>
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

provider:

```
"use client";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};

export default AuthProvider;
```

[image: redirect from home page]

[image: after refreshing page(loops indefinitely!!!)]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one helps you

```
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/client';

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context);

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/login',
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    props: { session },
  };
}

const Orders = ({ session }) => {
  ...
};

export default Orders;
```

Comment: i am using using nextjs 13 app folder structure so this unfortunately does not work with my project. however as @Mayank 's post suggests, i have to remove the async keyword at the page component. thnx